# SQL Every combination of ID's

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quite a tricky scenario. I have a table as below. Basically I want to get all combinations of ranges from each RangeSet in SQL Server 2012.

Best I show an example of structure and desired output. The problem is the number of RangeSetID's can be dynamic and the number of RangeID's can be dynamic in each range set

```
RangeID RangeSetID
------------------
1          4
2          4
3          4
4          4
5          2
6          2
7          2
8          2
9          2
10         2
11         1
12         1
13         1
14         1
15         1
16         1
17         3
18         3
19         3
20         3
```

I need the output to recursively create the below dataset of rates:

```
1 5 11 17  (first from range4, first from range2, first from range1, first from range3)
1 5 11 18 (first from range4, first from range2, first from range1, second from range3)
1 5 11 19 (first from range4, first from range2, first from range1, third from range3)
1 5 11 20 (first from range4, first from range2, first from range1, fourth from range3)
1 5 12 17 (first from range4, first from range2, second from range1, first from range3)
1 5 12 18 (first from range4, first from range2, second from range1, second from range3)
1 5 12 19
1 5 12 20
```

And so on until I reach the last RangeID from each RangeSetID and result in

```
4 10 16 20 (last from range4, last from range2, last from range1, last from range3)
```

Which will ultimately result in the below where RateID 1 is showing the first result vertically to allow for the dynamic number of RangeSetID's

```
RateID    RangeID
------------------
  1         1
  1         5
  1         11
  1         17
  2         1
  2         5
  2         11
  2         18
```

This should result in 11,000 rows (approx). I have tried CROSS JOIN's etc but I cannot get this working at all.

Any geniuses out there please?

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you explain how you got `1 5 11 17`

Comment: the number **n** - number of columns in result set  is equal to number of distinct `RangeSetID` so the general idea should be: get **n** alias tables as `select rangeID from table -- group by RangeSetID where  row_number = 1...n;`, then cross join **n** tables, get columns in each tables to the result set. Problem is how to get **n** and use it dynamically.

Comment: Updated as an edit.  My issue is the RangeSet's are dynamic and the number of RangeID's in the RangeSet is also dynamic

Comment: you can loop in your resultset and then write logic inside function or procedure. I think in this way it will be easier and simpler.

Comment: thanks @Avi but yes I have got this far so I am hoping I can work with this now SELECT [Range].[RangeID] AS [RangeID1],[Range2].[RangeID] AS [RangeID2],[Range].[RangeSetID],[Range2].[RangeSetID]
FROM [Range] 
INNER JOIN [Range] AS [Range2] on [Range].[RangeID] < [Range2].[RangeID]
WHERE [Range].RangeSetID <> [Range2].RangeSetID

Answer (score 0):

This sort of works, but it's way overcomplicated and could do with some tweaking.  Note that I changed your sample data, to include gaps to test this works properly.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (
    range_id INT,
    range_set_id INT);
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 1, 4;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 2, 4;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 3, 4;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 5, 4;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 8, 2;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 10, 2;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 17, 2;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 18, 2;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 19, 2;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 20, 2;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 21, 1;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 23, 1;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 28, 1;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 29, 1;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 30, 1;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 33, 1;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 35, 3;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 38, 3;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 39, 3;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 40, 3;

--Work out the order of the range_set_ids
WITH ordered AS (
    SELECT
        range_set_id,
        range_id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY range_set_id ORDER BY range_id) AS sequential_id
    FROM
        @table),
ranges AS (
    SELECT
        range_set_id,
        MIN(range_id) AS range_id
    FROM
        @table
    GROUP BY
        range_set_id),
range_order AS (
    SELECT
        range_set_id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY range_id) AS order_id
    FROM
        ranges),
set_count AS (
    SELECT
        MAX(order_id) AS max_order_id
    FROM
        range_order),
start_and_end AS (
    SELECT
        o.range_set_id,
        o.order_id,
        MIN(range_id) AS min_range_id,
        MAX(range_id) AS max_range_id,
        COUNT(range_id) AS iterations
    FROM
        range_order o
        INNER JOIN @table t ON t.range_set_id = o.range_set_id
    GROUP BY
        o.range_set_id,
        o.order_id),
toggles AS (
    SELECT
        s.range_set_id,
        s.order_id,
        s.iterations AS toggle
    FROM
        start_and_end s
        CROSS JOIN set_count c
    WHERE
        s.order_id = c.max_order_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        s.range_set_id,
        s.order_id,
        t.toggle * (s.iterations) AS toggle
    FROM
        toggles t
        INNER JOIN start_and_end s ON s.order_id = t.order_id - 1
    WHERE
        s.order_id > 0),
toggle_count AS (
    SELECT 
        MAX(toggle * s.iterations) AS max_toggle 
    FROM 
        toggles t
        CROSS JOIN set_count c
        INNER JOIN start_and_end s ON s.order_id = c.max_order_id),
all_combos AS (
    SELECT
        1 AS rate_set_id,
        o.range_set_id,
        1 AS sequential_id,
        o.order_id,
        lt.toggle AS reset_toggle,
        ISNULL(t.toggle, 1) AS increment_toggle,
        1 AS current_toggle
    FROM
        range_order o
        CROSS JOIN set_count c
        INNER JOIN toggles lt ON lt.order_id = o.order_id
        LEFT JOIN toggles t ON t.order_id = o.order_id + 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        a.rate_set_id + 1,
        a.range_set_id,
        CASE
            WHEN a.current_toggle = a.reset_toggle THEN 1 --flip back at the end
            WHEN a.current_toggle % a.increment_toggle != 0 THEN a.sequential_id --something lower is still toggling
            ELSE a.sequential_id + 1 --toggle
        END,
        a.order_id,
        a.reset_toggle,
        a.increment_toggle,
        CASE
            WHEN a.current_toggle < a.reset_toggle THEN a.current_toggle + 1
            ELSE 1
        END
    FROM
        all_combos a
        CROSS JOIN set_count sc
        CROSS JOIN toggle_count tc
    WHERE
        a.rate_set_id < tc.max_toggle)
SELECT
    a.rate_set_id,
    a.range_set_id,
    o.range_id
FROM
    all_combos a
    INNER JOIN ordered o ON o.range_set_id = a.range_set_id AND o.sequential_id = a.sequential_id
ORDER BY
    a.rate_set_id,
    a.order_id
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Comment: Mighty slow with 99 RangeID's and 4 RangeSets.  Good Effort though and thanks for trying!

Comment: Also the RangeID's may not be exactly incremental and there may be gaps...

Comment: Yes, I originally thought PIVOT for speed, but as you said this was dynamic it makes it a LOT harder to write something that works.  I was getting almost instant results on the sample data, but I can imagine that this wouldn't scale at all well...  I might have a bit more of a play with it, to see if I can cope with gaps, etc.

Comment: It's probably also worth mentioning that this doesn't lend itself to a SQL solution.  It would be trivial to solve this in .NET, or to write a RBAR SQL query, as opposed to a set-based solution.

Comment: Updated my answer with something that actually works, but is probably still far too slow...

Comment: I wrote a really long explanation of how it works, then stupid SO ate it :(

Answer (score 0):

Guess this should help. Happy coding!

```
;WITH CTE
AS
  (
  SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (order by [RangeID1] , [RangeID2], [RangeID3], [RangeID4]) as 'RateID', [RangeID1] , [RangeID2], [RangeID3], [RangeID4]  FROM 
  (
   select A.RangeID as [RangeID1], B.RangeID as [RangeID2], C.RangeID as [RangeID3], D.RangeID as [RangeID4]
    from [Range] as A
    inner join [Range] as B on (A.RangeID <= B.RangeID)
    inner join [Range] as C on (B.RangeID <= C.RangeID)
    inner join [Range] as D on (C.RangeID <= D.RangeID)
    where A.RangeSetID <> B.RangeSetID
    and B.RangeSetID <> C.RangeSetID
    and C.RangeSetID <> D.RangeSetID
  ) as A) T
  UNPIVOT ( RangeID FOR N IN ([RangeID1] , [RangeID2], [RangeID3], [RangeID4] ))P
  )
 SELECT RateID, RangeID
 FROM CTE
```

Comment: The number of Range Set's are dynamic so I don't know how many joins there will be, this is the dificulty

Answer (score 0):

Implemented same logic in dynamic query. This should work for you, I guess

```
 declare @i int = 1;
 declare @count int = 0;
 declare @cols varchar(max) = '';
 declare @select varchar(max) = 'select ';
 declare @join varchar(max);
 declare @where varchar(max);
 declare @query varchar(max);

 declare @range varchar(100);
 declare @prevrange varchar(100);
 declare @rangeid varchar(100);

 select @count =count(distinct RangeSetID) from [Range];

 while @count > 0
 begin

     set @range = 'Range' + cast(@i as varchar(max));
     set @rangeid = 'RangeID' + cast(@i as varchar(max));

     set @cols = @cols + @rangeid + ', ';
     set @select = @select + @range + '.RangeID as '+@rangeid + ', ';

      if @i = 1
        begin
            set @join = ' from [Range] as ' + @range;
            set @where = 'where ' + @range + '.RangeSetID <> ';
        end
      else 
        begin
            set @prevrange = 'Range' + cast((@i - 1) as varchar(max));
            set @join = @join + ' inner join [Range] as ' + @range + ' on (' + @prevrange + '.RangeID <= ' + @range + '.RangeID)';
            if(@count = 1)
                set @where = @where + @range+ '.RangeSetID';
            else 
                set @where = @where + @range+ '.RangeSetID and '+ @range+ '.RangeSetID <> ';
        end

     set @i = @i + 1;
     set @count = @count - 1;
 end 

 set @query = ' 
;WITH CTE
AS
  (
  SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (order by '+ SUBSTRING(@cols, 0, LEN(@cols)) + ') as ''RateID'', '+ SUBSTRING(@cols, 0, LEN(@cols)) +'  FROM 
  (
    ' + SUBSTRING(@select, 0, LEN(@select)) + char(13) + @join + char(13) + @where + '
  ) as A) T
  UNPIVOT ( RangeID FOR N IN ('+(SUBSTRING(@cols, 0, LEN(@cols))) +' ))P
  )
 SELECT RateID, RangeID
 FROM CTE
 ';

 exec (@query);
```